# How can I know when the button isn't clicked anymore

Tags: android, button, click

I have some problem - I must know when the button isn't clicked anymore. I need something like onClickListener which is executed when the user stops holding his finger on the button. Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can use ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN for that (check out the MotionEvent class). A MotionEvent is easily fetched using an onTouchListener. And you should show a lot more research effort. This is found within a matter of seconds if you search for it.

Comment: I've searched for that but I couldn't find it. I didn't know how to formulate the question in search engine - now I can see how obvious it is : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onTouchListener` and check for MotionEvent [`ACTION_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) (return `true` in your implementation to make Android know that you are handling the whole Touch event)

Comment: Thank you, it's really simple. I have could thought about that : )

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you should do is register *on touch* handler:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(listener)
```

and in the `listener` you should check the `event` if it's action is `ACTION_UP`. That's all.